# count all subsets of given array with sum equal to given sum

Tags: c++, string, vector, time-complexity, bitmask

### what can i do to optimize this code,if language will be c++ it will be more easy for me to understand.

Given an array of integers and a sum, the task is to count all  subsets of given array with sum equal to given sum.
Input : arr[] = {2, 3, 5, 6, 8, 10}, sum = 10,subsets are -> {5 2 3},
         {2 8},
         {10}, Output : 3 Input : arr[] = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5}, sum = 10, subsets are -> {4 3 2 1}, 
         {5 3 2 },
         {5 4 1},  Output : 3)

---

```
#include<bits/stdc++.h>

using namespace std;


string binary_string(int i,int len){

    string res="";
    int mod =0;

        while(i>0){
        mod = i%2;
        res+=to_string(mod);
        i/=2;
    }

    int n = res.length();

    if(n!=len){
        while(n!=len){
            res.append("0");
            n++;

        }


         return res;
    }



    return res;
}

int main()
{
   int t;
   cin>>t;

   while(t--){
    string binary;//,subseq;
    int n,k,count=0,sum,val;
    cin>>n;

    vector<int>vect;

    for(int i=0;i<n;i++){
        cin>>k;
        vect.push_back(k);
    }
    cin>>val;


    int bits_range = (int)pow(2,n) - 1;



    //cout<<"SUBSETS ARE :"<<endl;
    for(int i=0;i<=bits_range;i++){
        binary=binary_string(i,n);
        sum=0;
        for(int i=binary.length()-1;i>=0;i--){
            if(binary[i]=='1'){
                //subseq+=to_string(vect[i]);
                sum+=vect[i];

            }

        }
        if(sum==val){
            count++;
            //cout<<subseq<<endl;
            //subseq="";
        }
        //subseq="";
    }

        cout<<count<<endl;
   }



}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can sort the array and then use an idea similar to the [Two-Pointer Technique](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/two-pointers-technique/). The complexity is O(NlogN), or linear if you can sort in linear time.

**Edit:**
I explain better what I mean. `vect`is now the sorted version of the array. `partial` is the partial sum of the subarray [a,b).

```
int partial = 0;
int a = 0, b = 0;
int count = 0;
while (true) {
  if (partial == sum) {
    count++;
    a++;
  } else if (partial < sum) {
    if (b == vect.size()) {
      break;
    }
    partial += vect[b];
    b++;
  } else {
    partial -= vect[a];
    a++;
  }
}
```

Note that the both `a` and `b` can only increase, so the cycle has at most `2*vect.size()` iterations, so the complexity is linear.
After this `count` contains the answer.

You should check that this code works properly, but I hope you understand the idea from it.

Comment: but there may be triplets satisfying the condition , double pointer can search for pairs only

Comment: I've edited the answer to explain better what I was talking about

Comment: ok ok i got it but your code is not producing output when printing count, maybe it's going in infinite loop can you check your code once again

Comment: I forgot to increase ```a```(or ```b```, it's the same) when find a correct subset. Now should work. I've edited the code. I forgot to say that the solution works only if the array contain positive numbers